# Problems with Ubuntu 22 container from Jenkins server

Tags: docker, jenkins, ubuntu-22.04

A colleague of mine is having trouble running an Ubuntu 22 Docker container from inside a Jenkins server.  He has a Dockerfile to customize the image and can't do anything with `apt`:

```
+ docker run --rm ubuntu:22.04 bash -c 'apt-get update'
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:22.04' locally
22.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
677076032cca: Pulling fs layer
677076032cca: Verifying Checksum
677076032cca: Download complete
677076032cca: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:9a0bdde4188b896a372804be2384015e90e3f84906b750c1a53539b585fbbe7f
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:22.04
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Reading package lists...
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is not signed.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

This works fine if he uses an Ubuntu 20 container.  I have never used his Jenkins server/build environment and the server folks aren't helpful.  My team uses a different Jenkins server and doesn't have these problems.  I tried doing the exact same thing in my Jenkins server, I pulled the same Docker image, and it worked fine.

We're running out of ideas as to what's wrong.  Can anyone suggest how to get Ubuntu 22 working in this environment?

Comment: You may wanna add the Jenkins script to avoid getting downvoted.  It may help people replicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with a Jenkins script below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10')
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'develop', description: 'Enter branch name')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: 'Snapshot', description: 'Enter release version (example: Snapshot, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, ...)')
    }
    environment {
        JAR_ARTIFACT_NAME      = ""
    }
    stages {
        stage('Retrieve artifact') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'ubuntu:latest'
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }
            steps {     
                // Install something
                echo "Install something"
                echo "workspace = ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}") {
                    sh '''
                        apt-get update
                        apt-get install curl -y
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            node(null) {
                echo "Clean workspace"
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on my VM which runs Ubuntu 20.04.  However it gets the same error as you described on the deployment server, which runs Debian 11 (probably Centos 7).  Switching to Ubuntu 20.04 image makes the problem goes away.

```
image 'ubuntu:20.04'
```

Do you have to use Ubuntu 22.04?  Hopefully, someone can shed some light on this.